# How to determine currently sorted header column in data grid?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, datagrid, advanceddatagrid

I want to know which header the user clicked on to give the currently sorted view. 
Is there an API in flex framework that I can use to achieve this? Hopefully I can get back a column index so I know how it is currently sorted.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mx.controls.DataGrid` has a property named `columns`.  Each column in this collection is an object of type `mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn` with a boolean property named `sortDescending`.

Otherwise, you can receive and handle the DataGrid event `headerRelease`.  This event is transmitted when the user releases the mouse button on a column header, causing the column to become sorted.